# What could be wrong with the region and these S3 configs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, region, rails-activestorage

I keep getting this error, preventing aws deploy:

```
partition_matching_region': Cannot loadRails.config.active_storage.service: (NoMethodError) remote: undefined methodmatch' for nil:NilClass

config/storage.yml:

    amazon:
    service: S3
    access_key_id: <%= ENV['BUCKETEER_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %>
    secret_access_key: <%= ENV['BUCKETEER_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] %>
    region: <%= ENV['BUCKETEER_AWS_REGION'] %>
    bucket: <%= ENV['BUCKETEER_BUCKET_NAME'] %>
```

All of these are set with correct values in my own code.

In production.rb:

```
config.active_storage.service = :amazon
```

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the region is set correctly ? can you try to write it as hard coded instead of the environment variable for testing purposes ? just to ensure that its working ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As far as the region goes, it is the one that is shown for the account in which I have the bucket. I don't know how to otherwise make sure AWS has my region correctly, though I tried another region, which is probably closer to me, though I don't know if that  matters, and it didn't make any difference to my ability to connect the bucket with my code.

Comment: I haven't tried to make the connection with any hardcoding, without environment variables. The app has actually been working now on Heroku with all ActiveStorage/S3 code removed for the last two days so I'm not sure I needed ActiveStorage/S3 in the first place.